# disable opening pdf in browser php

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF plugin. I want to send email with pdf file. Everything is working fine. But, the problem is, after sending email my browser still shows the pdf file because of the content type header. Is there any way to disable that thing in certain condition?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there is. Add the relevant code so we know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$pdfContent = $pdf->Output('', 'S');` there shouldn't be any content send. See [here](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) for more details.